# Is the qur'an referring to the same creature in these two verses?

Tags: tafseer, end-times, creatures

In the Qur'an we find in surat an-Naml:

> And when the word befalls them, We will bring forth for them **a creature from the earth** speaking to them, [saying] that the people were, of Our verses, not certain [in faith]. ([27:82](https://legacy.quran.com/27/82))

This verse is often used as a reference when speaking about the so called creature from earth دابة الأرض. And the verse seems to indicate that this creature will only appear in the end times.

Nevertheless we find a verse in surat Saba' which seems to indicate that it already appeared:

> And when We decreed for Solomon death, nothing indicated to the jinn his death except **a creature of the earth** eating his staff. But when he fell, it became clear to the jinn that if they had known the unseen, they would not have remained in humiliating punishment. ([34:14](https://legacy.quran.com/34/14))

Are the two verses referring to the same creature? If not which is the other creature meant in the second verse?

Comment: 34:14 refers to the termite?

Comment: @Uma would you mind formulating that in an answer?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Why is there a connection between 27:82 and 34:14 and not for example [11:6](https://quran.com/11/6)

Comment: @Uma Maybe this needs an Arabic background. I was always assuming that there are two verses quoting this creature. However I was surprised that the only verse I could find beside 27:82 was 34:14 for which I have clear doubts to be the 2nd one. But I couldn't make out a better 2nd example, so my assumption seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not at all**

First one, verse 82 of Surat An-Naml talks a creature which will appear from the earth, has to happen.

The second one is talking about the "**Termite**"

If you know the history of death of Sulaiman (PBUH), then it will be clear:

> Sulaiman (PBUH) was sitting holding his staff, overseeing the jinns at
>   work. He died sitting in this position. For a long time, no one was
>   aware of his death, for he was seen sitting erect, so jinns were
>   continuously working.

After some time Termites eat the wood and he fall down and only then Jinns knew it.

Comment: A link to this hadith or a source would be helpful, else it was answered in Uma's comment already and I was considering to delete it.

Comment: Read the verse 2 3 times and you will get your answer, after Quran, there is no need to hadith.

Comment: I had my answer when asking the question already. I just want a good answer posted here or will consider deleting my question! So consider improving yours.